# Bug with MKMapView's centerCoordinate during rotation?

Tags: ios, ipad, mkmapview, mapkit, screen-rotation

I think I may have found a bug in `MKMapView`, but I'd like to run it by folks to see if anyone else has run into this issue. I'm using iOS 7 and Xcode 5.

In my storyboard, I have a view controller with an `MKMapView` in it. My app allows rotation to both portrait and landscape. I am using autolayout to keep the frame of the `MKMapView` updated when the user rotates the device.

After rotation, it appears that `MKMapView` is reporting an incorrect `centerCoordinate` in the `regionDidChangeAnimated` delegate method:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog(@"%@ %@", @(mapView.centerCoordinate.latitude), @(mapView.centerCoordinate.longitude));
}
```

When my view controller first loads in portrait orientation, I get the following output:

```
25.69266565483518 -40               
37.17818069458006 -96.05458068847656
```

After I rotate the device to landscape orientation, I get the following output:

```
9.656197790830817 -96.05458068847656
```

After I rotate the device back to portrait orientation, I get the following output:

```
37.17818069458006 -96.05458068847656
```

Finally, here are screenshots of both portrait and landscape orientations. I drew dots over the center of the images to show that--at least from a rendering perspective--the centers are the same.

[image: Portrait Orientation]
[image: Landscape Orientation]

Is this actually a bug as it appears or am I missing something?

EDIT:

I changed the code in `regionDidChangeAnimated` so that the `centerCoordinate` is outputted after a one millisecond delay. When I do this, I get correct results. However, this is not optimal and I still think that `centerCoordinate` should be updated by `MKMapView` *before* `regionDidChangeAnimated` is called.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 1 * NSEC_PER_MSEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
    {
        NSLog(@"%@ %@", @(mapView.centerCoordinate.latitude), @(mapView.centerCoordinate.longitude));
    });
}

37.17818069458006 -96.05458068847656
37.17818069458006 -96.05458068847656
37.17818069458006 -96.05458068847656
37.17818069458006 -96.05458068847656
```

EDIT:

I created a sample project in order to reproduce the bug for an Apple bug report. What I noticed that if the MKMapView is not embedded within a navigation controller, the centerCoordinate property always reports the correct value. As soon as I embedded it within a navigation controller--and turned off the "extend edges under top bars and bottom bars" options--it reported incorrect values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The defect I submitted to Apple was confirmed to be a duplicate. Looks like this is, indeed, a bug in MapKit.

Comment: Now that it is 2016 I am still seeing this bug, do you have a link to the bug report and status?

Comment: I am seeing a discrepancy with MKMapView centre coordinate too. I think it is related to how it calculates the views frame.