# Why isn't the center of my mapview's frame lining up its center coordinate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

I'm trying to render a circle at the center of a mapview.  I'm also displaying the user's current location on the mapview, and setting the center of the map to there.  These two are not lining up, though.

Here is where I set up my circle:

```
[self.mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];
CAShapeLayer *circle = [CAShapeLayer layer];
int radius = 50;
circle.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 2.0*radius, 2.0*radius)
                                         cornerRadius:radius].CGPath;
// Set position of the circle.
// We use the frame of the mapview subtracted by circle radius to determine the center
circle.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.mapView.frame)-radius,
                              CGRectGetMidY(self.mapView.frame)-radius);
circle.fillColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:0.5 green:0.5 blue:0.6 alpha:0.3].CGColor;
circle.strokeColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
circle.lineWidth = 1;

// Add to parent layer
[self.mapView.layer addSublayer:circle];

// Add 'crosshair'
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 5, 5);
[self.mapView addSubview:view];
view.center = self.mapView.center;
```

And in the didUpdateUserLocation delegate method I have:

```
    [self.mapView setCenterCoordinate:userLocation.coordinate];
```

Here's what it looks like on the simulator.

[image]

I eventually want to allow the user to pan and select a region of the map, but now I'm not sure if my centercoordinate of the map is even coinciding with the center of my circle.  Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be running into the same bug I discovered recently. I have reported it to Apple and it was marked as a duplicate, so perhaps it'll be fixed in iOS 7.1.

[Bug with MKMapView's centerCoordinate during rotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21615551/bug-with-mkmapviews-centercoordinate-during-rotation)

Comment: Think you might be right.  When I take the mapview out of the TabBarController, the center seems to coincide with center +10p for status bar.

Answer (score 1):

I think It's a status bar issue.

Try this.

```
[self.mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];
CAShapeLayer *circle = [CAShapeLayer layer];
int radius = 50;
circle.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 2.0*radius, 2.0*radius)
                                     cornerRadius:radius].CGPath;
// Set position of the circle.
// We use the frame of the mapview subtracted by circle radius to determine the center
circle.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.mapView.frame)-radius,
                          CGRectGetMidY(self.mapView.frame)-radius-20);
circle.fillColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:0.5 green:0.5 blue:0.6 alpha:0.3].CGColor;
circle.strokeColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
circle.lineWidth = 1;

// Add to parent layer
[self.mapView.layer addSublayer:circle];

// Add 'crosshair'
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 5, 5);
[self.mapView addSubview:view];
view.center = self.mapView.center;
```

I hope it works with you.

Comment: Adding to the Y moved it in the wrong direction.  I subtracted 10 and it was close.  Subtracting 15 of all numbers lines it up perfectly. (http://i.imgur.com/ymTZDae.jpg)  I'm looking for a formula that will work no matter where the mapview is, though, since I'm making a category of mapview.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a 20 point offset (same as the status bar). Perhaps your map view is being resized after you use the `frame` to find the center.

You might try using an `MKCircleView` or other overlays to do this instead of shape layers.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to track down if that's the case.  The exact offset is 15 strangely.  If I add a -15 to the Y it lines up.  I'm imagining it has something to do with a combination of the status bar and the tab bar.  Also, I'm using a shape layer rather than a circleview because I want the circle to be static in the center of the map as the user pans around.

Answer (score 0):

Using Xamarin.Forms, I had to make sure to enable the Safe Area Layout Guide, adding this to my `ContentPage` XAML.

```
<ContentPage ...
         xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
         Title="Safe Area"
         ios:Page.UseSafeArea="true">
<StackLayout>
    ...
</StackLayout>
```

For more info: [Safe Area Layout Guide on iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/ios/page-safe-area-layout)